# Import bootstrap in scss project + grunt + css compile load time

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gruntjs

I have setup SASS and Grunt. Every time I save my `main.scss` file, it will compile it to CSS. Perfect.

Now, in the top of `main.scss` I import bootstrap:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

However, when I do this, each SCSS -> CSS **compile takes around 8 seconds**!

Is there a smarter way to import bootstrap? I specially import it, because I need to make use of `extend`, i.e.:

```
.button {
    @extend .btn;
}
```

Comment: the whole bootstrap styles is something like 8000 lines, no wonder it takes a while; how about using a CDN or just compiling-importing the styles you're customizing

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 solutions and a bonus :

- don't compile bootstrap. Quick but you lose the @extend ".bootstrap-class". But do you really need to compile bootstrap just for that? Isn't adding the existing bootstrap classes to your html a better option ?
- compile bootstrap with just the minimum you need. Replace :

  `@import "bootstrap";`

by
a file containing the content of bootstrap.scss (in the bootstrap github repo that you npm-installed) where you comment/uncomment only what you really need :

```
// Core variables and mixins
//@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/variables";
@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset
//@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/normalize";
//@import "../vendor/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/print";
[...]
```

- use [libsass](http://libsass.org/) (with [grunt-libsass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-sass)) to compile bootstrap entirely (or not, see solution #2) and lower compilation time from 8s to something like 0.5s