# How to include Bootstrap in SCSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to include Bootstrap in an SCSS style sheet, as per [Import bootstrap in scss project + grunt + css compile load time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630697/import-bootstrap-in-scss-project-grunt-css-compile-load-time)

The style-sheet starts with

```
@import "boostrap.css";
```

(I copied the file bootsrap.css to the same directory.)

Then, from the shell command-line, I type:

```
scss style.css.scss
```

The output of this first line is

```
@import url(bootstrap.css)
```

Shouldn't the preprocessor have have compiled boostrap.css into the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import regular css file in scss file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111610/import-regular-css-file-in-scss-file)

Comment: You are right.  Thank you!  I'll leave it up in case it helps someone else because I don't think that trying this from a command-line is a common case.

Comment: Why you don't use the bootstrap sass? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: It's not a Rails app.  Just a static mockup.  But I wanted to do the stylesheet with SASS and Bootstrap b/c I'm spoiled.  :)